# Python googletrans library source langauge is only country code

Tags: python, google-translate

If I do

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator=Translator()

translated = translator.translate("Hi", dest = "tr")
print(translated.src)
```

It will only print country code which is equal to "en".
I want it to print language name's itself.
Like if the source langauge is "English",it should print **English** not **en** in my case.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `LANGUAGES` from `googletrans` to get the full name of language.

```
from googletrans import Translator, LANGUAGES
translator=Translator()

translated = translator.translate("Hi", dest = "tr")
print(LANGUAGES.get(translated.src))
```